# Preg_replace adds unwanted space between ALL characters

Tags: php, regex, html-table, preg-replace, removing-whitespace

I have an input from an HTML table.
First replacing wanted spacing by '_'. Then replacing HTML tags by spacing so I can extract the information by column.

I want my output to be:

> 100 Request_in_progress Pending_response 789653686

[Instead the output adds extra spacing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNS9h.png)

```
$testString = '<tr><td>100</td><td>Request in progress</td><td></td><td></td><td>Pending response</td><td>789653686</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
$rmSpace = str_replace(' ', '_', $testString);

$tags = '(<td>||</td>||<tr>||</tr>||<th>||</th>)';
$result = preg_replace($tags, ' ', $rmSpace);

echo $result;
```

Comment: You have `||` in your regex, it matches any empty string at the start/end of the string and between any chars inside the string. It is a typo, you should use a single `|`.

Comment: A tidier way of expressing this regex would be `preg_replace('~</?t[drh]>~', ' ', $rmSpace);`

Comment: If you are trying to grab content from HTML then rather than the ubiquitous Regex use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` - it is much, much simpler and more reliable

Comment: @RamRaider Depends on the use case. For scraping a bit of bit of data out of a table with a one-off script, I'd use regex every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the `regex` is incorrect.

In regular expressions, [the vertical bar (`|`)](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.alternation.php) joins alternative paths.

The expression `<td>||</td>` means "`<td>` OR *the empty string* OR `</td>`" (and so on but the rest already doesn't matter).

Accordingly, your `regex` matches all the HTML tags it contains but it also matches the empty strings between any two consecutive characters in the input string.

The correct `regex` is `<td>|</td>|<tr>|</tr>|<th>|</th>`.

```
$tags = '#<td>|</td>|<tr>|</tr>|<th>|</th>#';
$result = preg_replace($tags, ' ', $rmSpace);
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of how you achieve this using simple `DOMDocument`

```
$testString = '<tr><td>100</td><td>Request in progress</td><td></td><td></td><td>Pending response</td><td>789653686</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $testString );
$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
$out=array();

if( $col->length > 0 ) foreach( $col as $node )$out[]=str_replace(' ','_',$node->nodeValue);

$out=array_filter($out);
echo implode(' ',$out);
```